# Select record based on two tables

Tags: mysql

Suppose i have three table called bitrate, song and file.

**Table- Bitrate**

```
 -------------------------------
|  bitrate_id  | bitrate_name   |
---------------------------------
|      1       |    128kbps     |
---------------------------------
|      2       |    320kbps     |
---------------------------------
```

**Table- Song**

```
 -------------------------------
|  song_id     |   song_title   |
---------------------------------
|      1       |    My song 1   |
---------------------------------
|      2       |    My song 2   |
---------------------------------
```

**Table- file**

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  file_id     |     song_id    |   song_location  |   bitrate_id    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1       |       1        |      loc 1       |       1         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|      2       |       2        |      loc 2       |       1         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have an application where user create song and upload different bitrate track under the particular song. Suppose I have a song called "**My song 1**". When user add different bitrate track to this song user have to select the bitrate from select box generated from "

> SELECT * FROM bitrate

If user add **128kbps** track to "**My song 1**" and then when he upload another tarck to same song he can't select "**128kbps**" bitrate again. Mean I want to check if a song already have 128kbps bitrate song then when I query to bitrate table, just show other bitrate except "**128kbps**". How to acheive this? Thanks

Upload Form

[image]

Comment: You had better show us your form

Comment: Sorry I could not understand

Comment: You have a form where users enter the song name and bit rate, lets see it ( the HTML)

Comment: @RiggsFolly image uploaded.

Comment: If they have uploaded a 128 version remove that option from the dropdown

Comment: Yes I want that. But how to query from bitrate table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117828/discussion-between-ashis-biswas-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ello, mate. You can try to select the bitrates where the current song isn't using that using the condition **NOT IN**.

```
SELECT * FROM `bitrate` AS `b` WHERE b.bitrate_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT `bitrate_id` FROM `file` 
         WHERE `file_id` = {{here comes the actual file ID}}
    );
```

On the query above, we try to select the bitrates where its *bitrate_id* isn't present in some row at the table *file*

Read more about the **NOT IN** condition [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php)

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. But no luck